# Scala linearization with lazy vals, why infinite recursion?

Tags: scala

Trying to implement a structure that takes advantage of Scala's linearization, we've found some behavior that we don't understand.

While everything goes as intended if set the overridden field as `def`, it crashes with an infinite recursion loop if we set it as `lazy val`.

Code with defs:

```
trait T {
  def fields: List[Int] = Nil
}

trait A extends T {
  override def fields = 1 :: super.fields
}

trait B extends T {
  override def fields = 2 :: super.fields
}

val x = new B with A

println(x.fields)
```

Code with lazy vals:

```
trait T {
  def fields: List[Int] = Nil
}

trait A extends T {
  override lazy val fields = 1 :: super.fields
}

trait B extends T {
  override lazy val fields = 2 :: super.fields
}

val x = new B with A

println(x.fields)
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: circular dependencies with lazy vals are bad: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/improved-lazy-val-initialization.html

Comment: It's not circular. `A.fields` refers to `B.fields`, but `B.fields` does not refer to `A.fields`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the same case as https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3167

> Scala compiler bug: Stackable traits and lazy vals causing
>   StackoverflowException

```
trait Thing { def name: String }
trait Thing1 extends Thing { override lazy val name = "One" }
trait Thing2 extends Thing { abstract override lazy val name = super.name }
val t = new Thing with Thing1 with Thing2
t.name
```

results in `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

You can make it more similar.

```
trait Thing { def name: String = "" }
trait Thing1 extends Thing { override lazy val name = "One" }
trait Thing2 extends Thing { override lazy val name = super.name }
val t = new Thing with Thing1 with Thing2
t.name
```

This also results in `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

Anyway, this bug fix is fucking postponed.

```
Added the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.3'
Removed the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.2' 

Added the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.2'
Removed the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.1' 

Added the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.1-RC1'
Removed the Fix Version '2.11.1-RC1' 

Added the Fix Version '2.11.1-RC1'
Removed the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.0-RC1' 

Added the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.0-RC1'
Removed the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.0-M8' 

Added the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.0-M8'
Removed the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.0-M7' 

Added the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.0-M6'
Removed the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.0-M4' 

Added the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.0-M4'
Removed the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.0-M3' 

Added the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.0-M3'
Removed the Fix Version 'Scala 2.11.0-M2' 

...
```

With the issue reported in 2010.

I recommend not to use `lazy val`s that call `super` in stackable traits.